# More messy tags: [attachment] and [attachments]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

Currently, [attachment](/questions/tagged/attachment) has 765 questions, while [attachments](/questions/tagged/attachments) has 200.

I suspect *most* of the questions from each of these should be merged to [email-attachments](/questions/tagged/email-attachments), but there's a lot of badly tagged stuff on both that needs manual cleanup.  Also, it keeps piling up: as of this writing, [the latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383756/vb-form-send-an-email-with-form-fields-within-a-text-file-as-an-attachment) tagged with [attachment](/questions/tagged/attachment) is barely half an hour old.

I'd welcome any suggestions on what to do with these tags.  Blacklist, clean up, and merge?

---

**Edit:** Looks like [attachment](/questions/tagged/attachment) and [attachments](/questions/tagged/attachments) have been merged together, so now we only have a single problematic tag with 959 questions.  I guess that's a step in the right direction, so thanks, whoever did it.

Comment: It seems `attachments` has ben merged with `attachment`.